# How do i print all the first names whose address is Birmingham using python while loop? I am not sure where to start

Tags: python, while-loop

```py
dictionary_list = [
    {"firstname": "Steven", "lastname": "Walker", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "James", "lastname": "Kay", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "Alice", "lastname": "Gibson", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Doe", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "evan", "lastname": "spencer", "address": "Derby"},
    {"firstname": "Dean", "lastname": "Davis", "address": "Leeds"},
    {"firstname": "Jade", "lastname": "wilson", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "Emma", "lastname": "James", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "Alex", "lastname": "Windsor", "address": "Birmingham"},
    {"firstname": "Rebekah", "lastname": "Daphney", "address": "London"},
]
```

How do I print all the first names whose address is Birmingham using python while loop? I am not sure where to start.

Comment: Does it have to be a `while` loop? A `for` loop would be much better suited.

Comment: `while True:  print([d['firstname'] for d in dictionary_list if d['address'] == 'Birmingham']); break`

Comment: Yes, it can be done with for loop also, but a while loop would be much preferred. Thanks, Tobias.

Comment: Why? Is your actual question "how to do this?" or "how to do this exactly this way (because I already know the other way)?"

Comment: A `while` loop doesn't make sense here, a `for ... in ...` loop does. If you want to force yourself into a `while` loop as an exercise, you may be able to do so but it will be a worse solution like for example poping elements from the list in each iteration and doing it "while there are elements left to pop" or carrying a manual index "while it is lower than the list length". What alani did is not a `while` loop, it is a `for ... in ...` loop disguised inside a `while True` loop that always ends in the first iteration, so basically the while loop and the `break` are doing nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because you asked for implementation with `while` loop:

```
i = 0
while i < len(dictionary_list):
    d = dictionary_list[i]
    if d['address'] == 'Birmingham':
        print(d['firstname'])
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You firstly shouldn't use a `while loop` because it is no sence is your case, you better should use a `for loop` like that :

```
for d in dictionary_list:
    if d['address'] == 'Birmingham':
        print([d['firstname'])
```

But you can simply do that in one line as **alani** recommend you by doing that :

```
print([d['firstname'] for d in dictionary_list if d['address'] == 'Birmingham'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the pandas library, it's the most intuitive to start manipulating data on python :

```
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.DataFrame(dictionary_list)
    df2 = df[df['address']=="Birmingham"]
    print(df2["firstname"])
```